# Passing PHP form variables from one page to other

Tags: php

my php configuration on server are showing i can post variables to maximum size upto 8MB , thats enough .. but how to check for number of variables , sever is running ubuntu 4.4 , php .

i have a page which takes students marks and send them to a action page , but on action page doing echo for the post variables nothing is being displayed , where are doing an echo "hello"; this shows ...

this is the page which sends the variables

```
<form name="frm" action="marklistI.php" method="POST" class="" >
    <?php $tb->displayTable() ?>
    <div class="mainframe">
        <input type="hidden" name="batch" value="<?php print $_GET['batch']; ?>"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="sem" value="<?php print $_GET['sem']; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="chance" value="<?php print $_GET['chance']; ?>"/>
        <input name="submit" type="submit" class="hide" value="Save"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="url" value="<?php print $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

and this are the variables are coming to action page .. but on echo they are not showing any value .

```
$dept =$_COOKIE['dept'];
$join=$_POST['batch'];
$type='e';
$sem=$_POST['sem'];
$chance=$_POST['chance'];
```

Comment: can you please provide some sample code from your action page that's not working?  Are you using $_POST?

Comment: Try `var_dump($_GET); var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: $dept =$_COOKIE['dept'];
$join=$_POST['batch'];
$type='e';
$sem=$_POST['sem'];
$chance=$_POST['chance'];

Comment: please add the code to the main post...

Comment: and this are the variables are coming to action page ..  but on echo they are not showing any value .

Comment: have you checked the generated form (view source) ?

Comment: I moved the code from the comments to the post. Can someone please approve my edit?

Comment: guys m new here .. m nt able to post code in my post.

Comment: You can always edit your own question. Right, guys? Guys? ;)

Comment: @ratan: Everybody is able to post code in posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try placing this code on your action page:

```
if (isset($_GET)) {
    echo "<h3>GET METHOD</h3>";
    var_dump($_GET);
}
if (isset($_POST)) {
    echo "<h3>POST METHOD</h3>";
    var_dump($_POST);
}
if (isset($_COOKIE)) {
    echo "<h3>COOKIE METHOD</h3>";
    var_dump($_COOKIE);
}
```

See which method returns your variables and use it, otherwise, you are not filling any values on the form.

Answer (score 0):

this is your code:

```
<form name="frm" action="marklistI.php" method="POST" class="" > 
<?php $tb->displayTable(); ?>
<div class="mainframe"> <input type="hidden" name="batch" value="<?php print $_GET['batch']; ?>"/> 
<input type="hidden" name="sem" value="<?php print $_GET['sem']; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="chance" value="<?php print $_GET['chance']; ?>"/> 
<input name="submit" type="submit" class="hide" value="Save"/> 
<input type="hidden" name="url" value="<?php print $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>"/> 
</div> 
</form>
```

One possible reason for your issue:
You use "_GET[]" variables here but the form is POST. 
GET and POST are two different methods to send data, GET is in the URL path (a=&b=&c=) while POST is hidden in the HTML headers.
So make sure you read those results as "$_POST['name']"  and not GET.

I suggest this in the "receiving script" for debugging:

```
var_dump($_GET); 
var_dump($_POST);
```

And in your browser use Chrome or Firefox + Firebug and Press "f12".
In that debugger you can catch the POST when you click the button and you can look which variables were sent.
That should help you debug your issue fast.

One other suggestion, I personally would write the code less "mixed".
It makes it hard to read and hard to modify.
Why not like this:

```
<?php
echo "
<form name='frm' action='marklistI.php' method='POST' class='' >".
$tb->displayTable().
"<div class='mainframe'> 
<input type='hidden' name='batch'  value='$_GET[batch]'/> 
<input type='hidden' name='sem'    value='$_GET[sem]' />
<input type='hidden' name='chance' value='$_GET[chance]'/> 
<input name='submit' type='submit' class='hide' value='Save'/> 
<input type='hidden' name='url'    value='$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]'/> 
</div> 
</form> ";
?>
```

My guess for your problem is that those values in the formular are actually empty, that's why you don't receive anything.

Comment: the $_GET used here , is getting variables from the previous page , and then the form is using these variables to send to another page . and the variables posted above are the varables of the action page of this form . and doing echo they are not giving any value...

Comment: Try use the Debug feature and the var_dump I suggested
With var_dump it will echo ALL variables it received in the POST and GET array, so you can easily see what is going on.

Comment: GET METHOD

array(0) { }
POST METHOD

array(1001) { xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxCONFIDENTIALxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx }

Comment: wch means post method is giving variables to the next page right .

Comment: the problem is on doing var_dump it is shown that $_post is bringing the values from the form , but on doing...................................$dept =$_COOKIE['dept'];
$join=$_POST['batch'];
$type='e';
$sem=$_POST['sem'];
$chance=$_POST['chance'];.........................the values are nt shown why ???????

Comment: I notice that you've 1001 variables there. Did you check if the array item "batch" or "sem" is part of the array var_dump showed you ?
depending on your PHP setup it is possible you indeed run into an upper limit. For example the "suhoshin" security patch has such a limit (check /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/suhosin.ini ).
It's just a wild guess.

Comment: As i look ther server details ...      post_max_size 8M 8M is present wch means size of post var are fixed .. but there is no information about no of post variables .. help me finding that ..